# Continuous functions in a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a Tychonoff space $X$ and $F$ be a countable collection of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ such that $\cup\{f(A):f\in F\}=\mathbb{R}$. Can we prove that there exists a real-valued continuous function $g$ on $X$ such that $[0,1]\subseteq g(A)$?

Comment: You probably want $A$ to be a (uncountably) infinite set.

Comment: yeah... A has to be an uncountable set.